# The usage of "no" and "not" in the sentence

Tags: grammar

What should be used in the following sentence:"It's a cold month when there's not much sunshine"?Can I use "no" instead of "not" and why?

Answer (score 0):

"It's a cold month when there's not much sunshine."

or

"It's a cold month when there's no sunshine"

are both correct.

"It's a cold month when there's no much sunshine" is never correct.